# What's the mechanism of auto format of JetBrains IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

What is the mechanism for this auto format?

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-file-dialog.html

Is it a combination of `ESLint` plus `prettier`? I see nothing mentioned in the docs.

Comment: IntelliJ's reformat code uses its built-in rules and guidelines (which can be customized).  These can be slightly different by file type/language (depending on the standards for that language) - You can see/customize them by visiting `File Settings > Editor > Code Style` and select the style to view (i.e. HTML)

Comment: Actual help page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html